# Unique Calculated Totals with Parameters in Access Report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003, calculated-field

I'm working with an access 2003 report that uses an employee, and their points they've accumulated over a period of time.  When the report is run, it asks for parameters StartDate and EndDate, then generates a nice report by Supervisor -> Employee -> Each point with a reason.

How can I get a total box next to each employees name to give the total points for each employee?  I've thought about writing a SELECT and WHERE statement and adding variables to the VBA, so the source property is:

```
=(SUM(SELECT [PointValue] WHERE [EmployeeName] = CurrentEmployee AND & _
      [Date] <= #StartDate# AND [Date] >= #EndDate#))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use grouping. If you create a group header for the employee field (column) you can add a textbox and sum the points in the group header.

[image: report grouping]

Comment: Oh man.  After seeing what you did there I can now see how it pulls the data for the report and it worked like a charm.  Thanks Remou!